# Install Python package in linux OpenSUSe

Tags: package-management, python, opensuse

I am using this weird SuSE machine. 
I need to install a python package in my python 2.7. I downloaded it from the site and then `untar` it and cd to the directory.. 
Tried:

```
cd /python-package_Pyxnat/
python2.7 setup.py install
```

I am getting following output:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'
  warnings.warn(msg)
/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'summary'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat-1.0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyxnat-1.0.0.0-py2.7.egg-info
```

Error after importing pyxnat package:

```
>>> import pyxnat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pyxnat/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .core import Interface
  File "pyxnat/core/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .interfaces import Interface
  File "pyxnat/core/interfaces.py", line 8, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named requests
```

Why am I not able to import python package even after installing it?

Comment: Use a package manager. It used to be `zypper` for SUSE. Maybe it's now something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed the package, but not its dependencies. That is something running `python setup.py install` will not do for you, you better try a package manager like `pip` in which case you don't have download pyxnat first:

```
pip install pyxnat
```

which will get you all dependencies specified for `pyxnat`, not just the `requests` packages. Alternatively you can do:

```
pip install -e .
```

in the untarred pyxnat directory.

If you don't have pip installed use your package manager to install (probably called `python-pip`) or use the instructions [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing/).

I second @Digisec recommendation of using a virtualenv, especially if your python version is used by some system programs as well.

Comment: I totally forgot about dependencies. Removing my answer.